# How to animate pictures to grayscale one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have 3 images and i want animate them so they will turn grayscale after half of a second each one by one

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/PPDVy/

some example code:

```
  .wrap {
       overflow: hidden;
       background-color: #fff;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .box {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
       width: 14.285714286%;



    }

    .boxInner img {
       width: 100%;
       display: block;

    }

    .boxInner img:hover {
       -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to animate the images in sequence, you can try something like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes toGrayScale {
    to {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
}

.box:nth-child(1) img {
    -webkit-animation: toGrayScale 1s 0.5s forwards;
}

.box:nth-child(2) img {
    -webkit-animation: toGrayScale 1s 1s forwards;
}

.box:nth-child(3) img {
    -webkit-animation: toGrayScale 1s 1.5s forwards;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/PPDVy/5/)